# Spring Security Authentication not give 401 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

In a filter I have added below role in the spring security context.

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ANONYMOUS);
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthority = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuthority.add(authority);
        Authentication authentication = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(ANONYMOUS, ANONYMOUS, grantedAuthority);   
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        arg2.doFilter(arg0,arg1);
    }
```

Then from controller in a rest api method, i check the authorization role as below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class MyController { 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myservice1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")   
    public HttpEntity<String> myService() {
        System.out.println("-----------myService invoke-----------");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But when i invoke above API it successfully print the sysout. But it should give me a 401 unauthorized error right?

Comment: Did you enable method level security?

Comment: After adding @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) in SecurityConfig class, it works. If you can add it to the asnwer i will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enable method level security by:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```